# Find the number of relations between two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $A$ and $B$ be two finite sets. I'd basically need to find the number of all Relations $R \subseteq A\times B$, possessing the following properties:

a) $R$ is right-unique

b) $R$ is right-unique, but not left-total

c) $R$ is either left-total or not right-unique.

For the first two points I've come up with the following function to calculate all the right-unique relations from A, to B, containing all the subsets of A with respectively from 1 to n elements:
$$f(A, B, n) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \Biggl[C^i_{|A|}\cdot\sum_{k = 1}^{\min(i, |B|)}\bigg(V^k_{|B|}\bigg) \Biggr]$$

So I've come to the following results for the first two points:

a) right-unique relations: $S_1 = f(A, B, |A|)$

b) right-unique, but not left-total relations, which would mean the same as above, but without the case where the subset contains all the elements of A, so: $S_2 = f(A, B, |A| - 1)$

Now, what remains for c) is the hardest for me. Let's set:

$n(Lt)$ be the number of all left-total relations;

$n(Nru)$ be the number of all the non-righ-unique relations.

If we approach the issue logically, the statement would be equivalent to finding: $$n(Lt) + n(Nru) - n(Lt \cap Nru)$$

So far I've been able to find:
$$n(Lt) = \Bigr( \sum_{i = 1}^{|B|}C^i_{|B|}\Bigl)^{|A|}$$
$$n(Nru) = |B|^{|A|} - f(A, B, n)$$

At the end, my two questions would be:

1) Is the function $f(A, B, n)$ correct at what it should do? I suspect it's not fully correct for the case where $|A| > |B|$...
2) How can I calculate $n(Lt\cap Nru)$?

This has been a really interesting challenge for me, thanks a lot in advance to anyone who proposes help!

Comment: What do "right-unique" and "left-total" mean?

Comment: Right-unique means that a single element from A has maximal 1 corresponding value from B. Left-unique means that for every value in B maximal one corresponding value from A is.

Comment: Then (a) is $(|B|+1)^{|A|}$, because each element of $A$ either goes to an element of $B$ or to nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure that's quite right. Take the example of $A = \{1\}; B = \{a\}$. The number of relations is 1, with your formula 2. I mean, relations with nothing are no relations, shall not be counted.

Comment: Then just subtract $1$ from my formula.

Comment: @OscarCunningham What do you exactly mean, could you elaborate? I personally don't think this would be as simple...

Comment: @OscarCunningham I've now played around with what you've suggested and really the answer for a) is $(|B| + 1)^{|A|} - 1$! Thanks a lot!

Do you have any suggestions on the other points?

Comment: What does "left-total" mean? You told be above what "left-unique" meant, but not "left-total".